# Get all components injected in the specific one

Tags: java, spring, spring-framework-beans

I would like to add additional logic for all components injected into an object. I have a following code:

```
@Component
public class ItemA extends Item { /*...*/ }


@Component
public class ItemB extends Item { /*...*/ }


@Component
public class ItemC extends Item { /*...*/ }


public class Group {

    public void add(Item item) {
        // some logic here
    }
}


@Component
public class Group1 extends Group {

    @Autowired
    private ItemA itemA;

    @Autowired
    private ItemB itemB;

}


@Component
public class Group2 extends Group {

    @Autowired
    private ItemB itemB;

    @Autowired
    private ItemC itemC;

}
```

I would like to apply `add()` method for each injected component, i.e. `itemA` and `itemB` in case of `Group1` or `itemB` and `itemC` in case of `Group2`. Is it possible in Spring to do this "automatically" for all children of `Group` by some bean factory extension, AOP or others or do I have to do it manually in each `Group1`, `Group2`, etc?